# How to use $config->get for #default_value when multidimensional

Tags: 8, forms

I am creating a form and I want to store the form values every time the form is saved, so I am using:

```
'#default_value' => $config->get('field_name')
```

However what would I do if my form item rather than being

```
$form['field_name'] = [
  '#type' => 'datetime',
  '#default_value' => $config->get('field_name'),
  '#date_date_element' => 'none', 
  '#date_time_element' => 'time',
  '#date_time_format' => 'H:i',
];
```

was this

```
$form['section']['field_name'] = [
  '#type' => 'datetime',
  '#default_value' => $config->get('field_name'),
  '#date_date_element' => 'none', 
  '#date_time_element' => 'time', 
  '#date_time_format' => 'H:i',
];
```

I have tried unsuccessfully

```
'#default_value' => $config->get('section.field_name')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried unsuccessfully
>
> ```
> '#default_value' => $config->get('section.field_name')
> ```

Probably because you didn't set it first with `section.field_name` otherwise you can't retrieve it if you have not set it with that name.

---

Field names are supposed to be unique, so nothing different.

It really depends on what you do in **set**, you could give it whatever name you like

`$config->set('lalalala', $form_state->getValue('field_name'));`

and then retrive it with `$config->get('lalalala'),`

but convention is to give it the field name:

```
$config->set('field_name', $form_state->getValue('field_name'));
```